# Pre-built Erlang/OTP for RHEL

Tags: erlang, elixir, redhat, phoenix-framework

I need to deploy Phoenix/Elixir app onto a Redhat 7 server, which needs Erlang OTP installed. on the Erlang site, I don't see pre-built binary package for Redhat Linux. Can I use the CentOS version for RHEL?

Comment: I have CentOS spec files for erlang and elixir if your interested.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the  CentOS version for RHEL

**Also:**

You can install erlang using erlang-solution repo

Add the Erlang Solutions package:

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
rpm -Uvh erlang-solutions-1.0-1.noarch.rpm
```

Then install

```
sudo yum install erlang
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not direct answer but why you do not just use docker:

[elixir official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/elixir/)

[phoenix image](https://hub.docker.com/r/marcelocg/phoenix/)

This will ensure that everything will work in same way, even if you move your server in future, plus you will have image of your infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

Just to update this a bit, here's a set of instructions that work on Centos7/RHEL.

Open `~/.profile` with vi `~/.profile` and add the following:

```
export ERLANG_VERSION="19.1.5"
```

Then, run `source ~/.profile` and check env to make sure everything is set.

Next install some basics:

```
yum -y install --setopt=tsflags=nodocs epel-release wget unzip uuid less bzip2 git-core inotify-tools gcc
```

Then install Erlang:

```
yum -y install https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang/esl-erlang/FLAVOUR_1_general/esl-erlang_${ERLANG_VERSION}~centos~7_amd64.rpm && \
yum -y install esl-erlang-${ERLANG_VERSION} && \
yum -y update && \
yum -y reinstall glibc-common glibc
```